# run moleculer microservice via nats message

Tags: microservices, nats.io, moleculer

I'm beginner at moleculer and microservices . I created an api gateway via nestjs framework and now I want to call microservice in moleculer via nats messaging from nestjs. so my question is : How can I call a service in molculer and what is message pattern in nestjs to call moleculer action?

after creating a template via molculer I have bellow files and I want to call "greeter.hello" action. How can I do?

greeter.service.js :

```
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {import('moleculer').Context} Context Moleculer's Context
 */

module.exports = {
    name: "greeter",

    /**
     * Settings
     */
    settings: {
    },

    /**
     * Dependencies
     */
    dependencies: [],

    /**
     * Actions
     */
    actions: {

        /**
         * Say a 'Hello' action.
         *
         * @returns
         */
        hello: {
            rest: {
                method: "GET",
                path: "/hello"
            },
            async handler() {
                return "Hello Moleculer";
            }
        },

        /**
         * Welcome, a username
         *
         * @param {String} name - User name
         */
        welcome: {
            rest: "/welcome",
            params: {
                name: "string"
            },
            /** @param {Context} ctx  */
            async handler(ctx) {
                return `Welcome, ${ctx.params.name}`;
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Events
     */
    events: {

    },

    /**
     * Methods
     */
    methods: {

    },

    /**
     * Service created lifecycle event handler
     */
    created() {

    },

    /**
     * Service started lifecycle event handler
     */
    async started() {

    },

    /**
     * Service stopped lifecycle event handler
     */
    async stopped() {

    }
};
```

moleculer.config.js :

```
"use strict";

/**
 * Moleculer ServiceBroker configuration file
 *
 * More info about options:
 *     https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/configuration.html
 *
 *
 * Overwriting options in production:
 * ================================
 *  You can overwrite any option with environment variables.
 *  For example to overwrite the "logLevel" value, use `LOGLEVEL=warn` env var.
 *  To overwrite a nested parameter, e.g. retryPolicy.retries, use `RETRYPOLICY_RETRIES=10` env var.
 *
 *  To overwrite broker’s deeply nested default options, which are not presented in "moleculer.config.js",
 *  use the `MOL_` prefix and double underscore `__` for nested properties in .env file.
 *  For example, to set the cacher prefix to `MYCACHE`, you should declare an env var as `MOL_CACHER__OPTIONS__PREFIX=mycache`.
 *  It will set this:
 *  {
 *    cacher: {
 *      options: {
 *        prefix: "mycache"
 *      }
 *    }
 *  }
 */
module.exports = {
    // Namespace of nodes to segment your nodes on the same network.
    namespace: "mole",
    // Unique node identifier. Must be unique in a namespace.
    nodeID: "users",
    // Custom metadata store. Store here what you want. Accessing: `this.broker.metadata`
    metadata: {},

    // Enable/disable logging or use custom logger. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/logging.html
    // Available logger types: "Console", "File", "Pino", "Winston", "Bunyan", "debug", "Log4js", "Datadog"
    logger: {
        type: "Console",
        options: {
            // Using colors on the output
            colors: true,
            // Print module names with different colors (like docker-compose for containers)
            moduleColors: false,
            // Line formatter. It can be "json", "short", "simple", "full", a `Function` or a template string like "{timestamp} {level} {nodeID}/{mod}: {msg}"
            formatter: "full",
            // Custom object printer. If not defined, it uses the `util.inspect` method.
            objectPrinter: null,
            // Auto-padding the module name in order to messages begin at the same column.
            autoPadding: false
        }
    },
    // Default log level for built-in console logger. It can be overwritten in logger options above.
    // Available values: trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal
    logLevel: "info",

    // Define transporter.
    // More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/networking.html
    // Note: During the development, you don't need to define it because all services will be loaded locally.
    // In production you can set it via `TRANSPORTER=nats://localhost:4222` environment variable.
    transporter: "nats://localhost:4222", //"NATS"

    // Define a cacher.
    // More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/caching.html
    cacher: null,

    // Define a serializer.
    // Available values: "JSON", "Avro", "ProtoBuf", "MsgPack", "Notepack", "Thrift".
    // More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/networking.html#Serialization
    serializer: "JSON",

    // Number of milliseconds to wait before reject a request with a RequestTimeout error. Disabled: 0
    requestTimeout: 10 * 1000,

    // Retry policy settings. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/fault-tolerance.html#Retry
    retryPolicy: {
        // Enable feature
        enabled: false,
        // Count of retries
        retries: 5,
        // First delay in milliseconds.
        delay: 100,
        // Maximum delay in milliseconds.
        maxDelay: 1000,
        // Backoff factor for delay. 2 means exponential backoff.
        factor: 2,
        // A function to check failed requests.
        check: err => err && !!err.retryable
    },

    // Limit of calling level. If it reaches the limit, broker will throw an MaxCallLevelError error. (Infinite loop protection)
    maxCallLevel: 100,

    // Number of seconds to send heartbeat packet to other nodes.
    heartbeatInterval: 10,
    // Number of seconds to wait before setting node to unavailable status.
    heartbeatTimeout: 30,

    // Cloning the params of context if enabled. High performance impact, use it with caution!
    contextParamsCloning: false,

    // Tracking requests and waiting for running requests before shuting down. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/context.html#Context-tracking
    tracking: {
        // Enable feature
        enabled: false,
        // Number of milliseconds to wait before shuting down the process.
        shutdownTimeout: 5000,
    },

    // Disable built-in request & emit balancer. (Transporter must support it, as well.). More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/networking.html#Disabled-balancer
    disableBalancer: false,

    // Settings of Service Registry. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/registry.html
    registry: {
        // Define balancing strategy. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/balancing.html
        // Available values: "RoundRobin", "Random", "CpuUsage", "Latency", "Shard"
        strategy: "RoundRobin",
        // Enable local action call preferring. Always call the local action instance if available.
        preferLocal: true
    },

    // Settings of Circuit Breaker. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/fault-tolerance.html#Circuit-Breaker
    circuitBreaker: {
        // Enable feature
        enabled: false,
        // Threshold value. 0.5 means that 50% should be failed for tripping.
        threshold: 0.5,
        // Minimum request count. Below it, CB does not trip.
        minRequestCount: 20,
        // Number of seconds for time window.
        windowTime: 60,
        // Number of milliseconds to switch from open to half-open state
        halfOpenTime: 10 * 1000,
        // A function to check failed requests.
        check: err => err && err.code >= 500
    },

    // Settings of bulkhead feature. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/fault-tolerance.html#Bulkhead
    bulkhead: {
        // Enable feature.
        enabled: false,
        // Maximum concurrent executions.
        concurrency: 10,
        // Maximum size of queue
        maxQueueSize: 100,
    },

    // Enable action & event parameter validation. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/validating.html
    validator: true,

    errorHandler: null,

    // Enable/disable built-in metrics function. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/metrics.html
    metrics: {
        enabled: true,
        // Available built-in reporters: "Console", "CSV", "Event", "Prometheus", "Datadog", "StatsD"
        reporter: {
            type: "Prometheus",
            options: {
                // HTTP port
                port: 3030,
                // HTTP URL path
                path: "/metrics",
                // Default labels which are appended to all metrics labels
                defaultLabels: registry => ({
                    namespace: registry.broker.namespace,
                    nodeID: registry.broker.nodeID
                })
            }
        }
    },

    // Enable built-in tracing function. More info: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/tracing.html
    tracing: {
        enabled: true,
        // Available built-in exporters: "Console", "Datadog", "Event", "EventLegacy", "Jaeger", "Zipkin"
        exporter: {
            type: "Console", // Console exporter is only for development!
            options: {
                // Custom logger
                logger: null,
                // Using colors
                colors: true,
                // Width of row
                width: 100,
                // Gauge width in the row
                gaugeWidth: 40
            }
        }
    },

    // Register custom middlewares
    middlewares: [],

    // Register custom REPL commands.
    replCommands: null,

    // Called after broker created.
    created(broker) {

    },

    // Called after broker started.
    async started(broker) {

    },

    // Called after broker stopped.
    async stopped(broker) {

    }
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the nats moleculer, this is message [transport](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.14/networking.html). Messages themselves work according to the [protocol](https://github.com/moleculerjs/moleculer/blob/master/docs/PROTOCOL.md). Answer: this cannot be done with a simple message. It is necessary to implement the protocol completely.

Comment: Maybe check it: https://github.com/jiangzhuo/nestjs-moleculer

Answer (score 1):

As Ivan explained , we can not use message patterns directly. so how can we send messages to a moleculer framework from another framework like nestjs?

we should add moleculer service broker library to our gateway framework (nestjs).
bellow library helped me to connect other nodes .

[nestjs-moleculer](https://github.com/jiangzhuo/nestjs-moleculer#call-service-handler)